# How to link all C files automaticly in VSCODE?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I have lots of `.c` files and `.h` files and I want to compile all of them. But I find I must add every filename manually in `tasks.json`. Is there any way to link all the `.c` files in the same folder?

Answer (score 0):

You must still have a make system for your project for instance a Makefile.

So you should create a build rule in your Makefile and the run `make` from tasks.json

Here is an [example I have on github](https://github.com/simonsso/empty-cpp-project), it is for C++ but the concept is the same for C.

Comment: The question is not fully answered because you show only simple project with main.cpp and not complex structure with header files, libs etc.

Comment: @OndrejRozinek, feel free to add another answer, if it is good I will upvote it. Sometimes even an incomplete answer can push someone in the right direction.